# Как открыть сайт в PyQt5

Tags: python, веб-программирование, pyqt5

Недавно, я задался вопросом, как в PyQt5 открыть веб-страницу. Но я не понимаю как это сделать. Можете помочь в этом как-то?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebview-minibrowser-example.html

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1165604 ? Что именно вам не понятно?